# NGINX Websockets, and SSL Configuration

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to setup a websocket connection (wss). My domain uses ssl (certbot) and is powered by Nginx. I am unsure how to configure my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com` file.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
...
}
```

I added the following into my config block:

```
location /websocket {
    proxy_pass         https://domain.com;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

When connecting via: `wss://domain.com/`, I am getting an error of

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.com/' failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

Most of the examples out there are using a nodejs framework to serve their sites, but I am using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your websocket endpoint is configured in the provided nginx configuration as hosted at the location `/websocket` within the server, but you are attempting to connect to the root URL `wss://domain.com`.

The websocket connection is an ordinary HTTP (with a TLS wrapper in this case) session until the upgrade takes place, so you must ensure the URL used to access the service includes all relevant path designators, e.g. `wss://domain.com/websocket`.

Comment: I understand that, sorta... However, I am getting `WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.com/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500` with that setup, so unsure if it is my config or a port that needs to be configured?

Comment: What is hosted on `https://domain.com`? 500 indicates a server error, most probably from the back-end you're proxying to, while trying to respond to the web socket request. Check the PHP application is correctly receiving the web socket request and is speaking web socket in response. Its logs may provide further assistance in this respect.

Comment: A php cms (OctoberCMS). https://pvpaissa.com/broadcast/panel/match/score/testslug

I'm using a websocket plugin. It works on my local macbook... The issue came after trying to set it up on my live server (ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: I found this article, will try and see if it bears fruit tomorrow https://modalduality.org/posts/deploying-websockets-secure-with-nginx-and-systemd/

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Now I need to see how to keep my connections active.